# Graph API photo upload with friend tag

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I want is to post a status from android application, that status contains an image, some people tagged in it. When I post status with person tagged only or only with photo it is working absolutely fine. Problem comes when i add a photo with tags and then post it on fb, my profile shows nothing.

```
 btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (String s : user_friends_id) {
                ids += s + ",";
            }
            if (etxt_status.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(FacebookStatusUpdate.this, "Status is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else /*if (bitmapdata != null)*/ {
                btn_submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                user_status = etxt_status.getText().toString();
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("caption", etxt_status.getText().toString());
                params.putString("place", user_loc_id);
                params.putString("tags", ids);
                params.putByteArray("picture", bitmapdata);

                new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        "/" + user_fb_id + "/photos",
                        params,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                //new getPlaceId().execute();
                                JSONObject o = response.getJSONObject();
                                try {
                                    user_status_id = o.getString("id");
                                } catch (Exception ex) {

                                } finally {
                                    new insertCheckinDetails().execute();
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(FacebookStatusUpdate.this, "Status Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();
            } 
        }
    });
    url_paging = new ArrayList<>();
    friends = new ArrayList<>();
    fb_name = new ArrayList<>();
    fb_id = new ArrayList<>();
    fb_images = new ArrayList<>();
    ls_json_obj = new ArrayList<>();
    new abc().execute();
}
```

Used this link [Graph API Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine to upload the image on facebook without friend tag, to tag the friends with your image you have to make the following change. Replace

```
for (String s : user_friends_id) {
    ids += s + ",";
}
```

and

```
params.putString("tags", ids);
```

With

```
String tagFriendListId="";
for(int i=0;i<user_friends_id.size();i++)
{
    tagFriendListId = tagFriendListId+"          {'tag_uid':'"+user_friends_id.get(i)+"'} ,";
}
tagFriendListId=tagFriendListId.substring(0,      tagFriendListId.length()-1);
```

and

```
params.putString("tags","["+tagFriendListId+"]");
```